# FFMPEG batch for loop with multiple inputs

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, batch-processing

*What we have:*

**test.mp3
test.mp4**

*We want to merge this using ffmpeg*

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp3" -i "test.mp4" -c copy D:\test_final.mp4
```

The thing is we just need this to do for tons of videos.

*What we currently have:*

```
for %%a in ("merge\*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%a" -c copy D:\%%~na
```

So, what's the correct form? I have no idea :/

**In `merge` there are always mp3 and mp4 files with the same name.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have looks pretty darn good, and you didn't describe exactly ***how*** it does not work for you.

To match your desired line more exactly:

- Get only `*.mp3` files
- Use `%%~pa%%~na` to get the path and filename-only, but no extension, then add a `.mp4` on the end of it.
- Add a `_final` to the resulting name

---

If this isn't working for you, please describe exactly how it fails.

```
for %%a in ("merge\*.mp3") do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%~pa%%~na.mp4" -c copy D:\%%~na_final.mp4 )
```

Comment: It works great! thx alot :) And how to delete the old ones? just `DEL %%a` and `DEL %%~pa%%~na.mp4` does not work.

Comment: Rejected the edit, as the variety of options passed to the program is not part of the problem / question.  Passing the right params is up to the Poster.  I'm only answering how to get the proper file names.

Comment: @JackBrown Be aware that the default [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior may not necessarily always choose the correct streams. I edited this answer to avoid this, but abelenky did not like anyone else touching their answer and reverted it.